# Hibernate: either null foreign key, or duplicate foreign keys for OneToOne related entity

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

Started with getting a hibernate exception on a "select * from **PARENT**" type of a query, which said I have more than one entry in the **CHILD** table with the same [foreign] key, which should be unique. That was a red herring - the **CHILD** table had no such entries. I wiped the table clean, and moved on to the same error, this time citing **ANOTHER_CHILD** as an offender. In fact **ANOTHER_CHILD** only has 1 row...

Here, `CHILD` table(s) store persistent `@Entity`(s), which are in a bi-directional `@OneToOne` relationship with **Parent** `@Entity`.

NOTE: **PARENT** tables has a primary key, `PARENT_PK`, and there is a `PARENT_PK` column on all "Children", which points to the PARENT entry, which 'owns' the CHILD.

It was suggested to me that the problem is likely due to the bi-directionality of the relationship(s); and that I should make them uni-directional, if possible. OK, as I don't really need bi-directionality, I changed the annotations and made made relationship(s) uni-directional. Now the "get all" kind of a request works fine - but now *updating* the **Parent**, adding new **Child**, is failing with a `ConstraintViolationException: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into CHILD.PARTNER_PK`

I also found this article:
[Target Foreign Keys, Primary Key Join Columns, Cascade Primary Keys](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToOne#Target_Foreign_Keys.2C_Primary_Key_Join_Columns.2C_Cascade_Primary_Keys)

it claims uni-directional relationships are not supported when the the foreign key is in the "child" table, which the object relationship is to be unidirectional from Parent to Child. It's not clear on how to solve it, though.

I am looking for either of the solutions:

1) how to fix the bi-directional mapping to avoid the bogus "duplicate id" exception
2) how to make the relationship uni-directional, without changing the schema

.....

Code snippets:

This is how the relationship *was* defined in the `Parent`:

> ```
> @OneToOne(mappedBy = "parent",
>         cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
>         fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
>         orphanRemoval = true)
> private Child child;
> ```

And this is what was in the Child:

> ```
> @OneToOne
> @JoinColumn(name="PARTNER_PK")
> private Parent parent;
> ```

, (+ all the getters/setters).

After attempting the change for uni-directional relationship, Child class doesn't have the Parent at all. Parent class now looks like this:

> ```
> @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
> @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_PK")
> private AddressDO address;
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Gave up on making one-to-one unidirectional, and fixed the bidirectional like so:

In Parent class:

> ```
> @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "parent", orphanRemoval = true)
> private Child child;
> ```

In Child class:

> ```
> @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
> @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_PK", insertable = true, updatable = false, nullable = false)
> private Parent parent;
> ```

Still not sure what the real cause was for the problem, though =(